# Android - Google Sample HdrViewFinder in Portrait Mode

Tags: android, android-camera2, aspect-ratio, landscape-portrait

can somebody help me out with the following code. I want to transform the `HdrViewFinder` project from google samples (https://github.com/googlesamples/android-HdrViewfinder) so that it also works in portrait mode. But the project works only in landscape mode.
In portrait mode, the camera preview gets distorted.

So, here is the method I extracted from the HdrViewfinderActivity.java class which I think is responsible for setting the whole view into landscape:

```
/**
     * Configure the surfaceview and RS processing.
     */
    private void configureSurfaces() {
        // Find a good size for output - largest 16:9 aspect ratio that's less than 720p
        final int MAX_WIDTH = 1280;
        final float TARGET_ASPECT = 16.f / 9.f;
        final float ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1f;

        StreamConfigurationMap configs =
                mCameraInfo.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
        if (configs == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot get available picture/preview sizes.");
        }
        Size[] outputSizes = configs.getOutputSizes(SurfaceHolder.class);

        Size outputSize = outputSizes[0];
        float outputAspect = (float) outputSize.getWidth() / outputSize.getHeight();
        for (Size candidateSize : outputSizes) {
            if (candidateSize.getWidth() > MAX_WIDTH) continue;
            float candidateAspect = (float) candidateSize.getWidth() / candidateSize.getHeight();
            boolean goodCandidateAspect =
                    Math.abs(candidateAspect - TARGET_ASPECT) < ASPECT_TOLERANCE;
            boolean goodOutputAspect =
                    Math.abs(outputAspect - TARGET_ASPECT) < ASPECT_TOLERANCE;
            if ((goodCandidateAspect && !goodOutputAspect) ||
                    candidateSize.getWidth() > outputSize.getWidth()) {
                outputSize = candidateSize;
                outputAspect = candidateAspect;
            }
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "Resolution chosen: " + outputSize);

        // Configure processing
        mProcessor = new ViewfinderProcessor(mRS, outputSize);
        setupProcessor();

        // Configure the output view - this will fire surfaceChanged
        mPreviewView.setAspectRatio(outputAspect);
        mPreviewView.getHolder().setFixedSize(outputSize.getWidth(), outputSize.getHeight());
}
```

How could I change this method so that it works also in portrait mode? What do I need to change ? 
Setting only the `screenOrientation` attribute in the manifest file to `portrait` did not help.
I have found out the `16:9` is used for full landscape mode and that `9:16` used for full portrait mode. So, I changed `MAX_WIDTH` to `720` and `TARGET_ASPECT` to `9.f/16.f` . But that also did not help.

Can somebody provide a solution ?

Here is a little sketch showing the problem/what happens when I just set the `screenOrientation` attribute in the manifest file to portrait mode:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an [experimental fork](https://github.com/alexcohn/android-HdrViewfinder/tree/enable_portrait) that achieves this, by switching to TextureView from SurfaceView.

*tested on Sony G8441 a.k.a Xperia XZ1 Compact with **Android Pie***

Comment: Thank you, your project was a great help. I studied a little bit and the method I need was the setRotation() call on the TextureView instance.

Comment: Oh, I must admit that I used that HdrViewfinder project for a different purpose. I was just interested in combining Camera2 API with renderscript for image/video processing. There is not much projects out there regarding renderscript with camera2. The HdrViewfinder part did not interested me so much. So, I did not test it. Sry

Comment: That's OK. I'm glad that my advise could help.